# dbt incremental model with merge incremental strategy for Snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am incrementally updating a Snowflake table with dbt incremental model with merge incremental strategy to avoid duplicated records.

I have provided the following configurations to my dbt SQL model but it looks like this model is deployed as append mode. dbt run command insert duplicated records.

Am I missing any configurations?

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        uniqeue_key='event_date',
        incremental_strategy='merge'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `unique_key`.